# editing and removing objects from an array of objects in php

Tags: php

as the title says, I have a `table` that contains rows from a JSON decoded array in the name of `decoded`
the last `column` in the `table` holds to `buttons` one for `editing` and the other for `removing` the `row` I'm trying to understand how to make this `buttons` edit and remove the rows from the `table` and from there objects in the `decoded` Array

[image: table]

table.php

```
<table class="table" style="direction: rtl;" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>إسم المنتج</th>
            <th>سعر القطعة</th>
            <th>تاريخ الإنتاج</th>
            <th>تاريخ إنتهاء صلاحية</th>
            <th>الكمية</th>
            <th>Free</th>
            <th>السعر النهائي</th>
            <th>إجراءات</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-family: Tahoma; text-align:right;">
        <tr>
        <!-- Parsing $billingJSON to the table -->
        <? foreach ($decoded as $Product){?>
            <td scope="row">1</td>
            <td><?=$Product->name;?></td>
            <td><?=$Product->price;?></td>
            <td><?=$Product->productiondate;?></td>
            <td><?=$Product->expirationdate;?></td>
            <td><?=$qty=50;?></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><?=$pricewsale = $Product->price * $qty?></td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-times remove-symbol" onclick="RemoveItem();">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i><i class="fas fa-marker edit-symbol" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modelId"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <?}?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Core.php Contains functions to get some keys `value`

```
<?PHP
public function getBillItems($BillID)
{
    if($this->connected === true){
        try{
            $items = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE id=:id");
            $items->bindParam(":id",$BillID);
            $items->execute();
            return $items->fetchColumn();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            if($this->errors === true){
                return $this->error($e->getMessage());
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public function getPrice($id,$codenumber){
    if($this->connected === true){
        try{
            $items = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE id=:id");
            $items->bindParam(":id",$id);
            $items->execute();
            $fetchedItems = $items->fetchColumn();
            $items = json_decode($fetchedItems);
            $array = array_column($items, null, 'codenumber');
            return $array[$codenumber]->price; 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            if($this->errors === true){
                return $this->error($e->getMessage());
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So you need to write a Javascript function called `RemoveItem()` and in there make an AJAX call to a PHP script that will remove this row. Thenn you remove the row from the HTML table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, but what about editing? I think its more complicated right?

Comment: Not a lot more difficult, but you will have to provide a dialog for the user to edit or make those table fields into a FORM so the changes can be recorded

Comment: @RiggsFolly but how to pass the fields to the Dialog? the problem is each row need to be indexed, I'm really confused how can I do that?